# Return all documents for record on public site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, relationships, files

I have a public site where I pass a record id via URL parameter.  I show the related list of the files.  I can do this when I preview the site from the developer console. But when I do this from the "preview as admin" on the site, I get this error:

> *ERROR 'attachedcontentdocuments' is not a valid child relationship name for entity MyCustomObject__C*

My next attempt is to build the document list into the controller.  But AttachedContentDocuments are not query-able.  I think they are attached to a ContentDocument but I don't know what those are attached to.  What is the relationship from my custom object down to the AttachedContentDocuments?

Also, will this just be a fools errand trying to expose attached files on record through public site?  Even still, I'm still curious of the relationship from an object to it's AttachedContentDocuments

```
<apex:page controller="ORR_Extension" showHeader="false" showChat="false">
<!--<apex:page standardController="ORR_Extension" showHeader="false" showChat="false">-->

<style type="text/css">
    .pbButton{
    display:none;
    }    
</style>
<apex:slds />

<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Open Records Request">

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ORR}" var="ORR">
            <apex:column value="{!ORR.Status__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!ORR.Subject__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!ORR.Due_Date__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<apex:relatedList subject="{!ORRid}" list="AttachedContentDocuments" />
```